# Changing levelplot labels in R

Tags: r

I'm making a levelplot in R:

```
levelplot(cov(data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(4,5,6), c=c(1,5,9))))
```

Instead of the names on the plot being a, b, and c, I want them to be expressions, like

```
labels <- expression(alpha, beta, omega**2)
```

How can I put these labels in? Thanks.

Comment: Would that be `levelplot` from `lattice`?

Comment: Why not `levelplot(cov(data.frame("alpha"=c(1,2,3), "beta"=c(4,5,6), "omega**2"=c(1,5,9))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the label to `scales` argument as a named list (see `xyplot` documentation).

```
library(lattice)

xy.labels <- expression(alpha, beta, omega**2)
levelplot(cov(data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(4,5,6), c=c(1,5,9))), scales = list(labels = xy.labels))
```

[image]